# Question regarding projective resolution

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

I was reading about projective resolution and I came across this following definition:

A projective resolution of an R-module M is a complex X together with an R-linear map $ X_0 \xrightarrow \epsilon M$ such that the sequence

$.... \rightarrow X_n \xrightarrow {d_{n}}  X_{n-1}......X_1\xrightarrow {d_{1}} X_0 \xrightarrow \epsilon M\rightarrow 0 $ is exact and all the $X_i$ are $R$-projective.

Clearly X has a property that $H_n(X) =0$ , $n>1$, and $H_0(X) \cong M$, where $H_n(X)= \frac{ker(d_n)}{im(d_{n+1})}$

I couldn't understand the last sentence, i.e how can we prove  $H_0(X) \cong M$. From the definition of homology we can see 
$H_0(X)= \frac{ker(d_0)}{im(d_1)}$. But the sequence is exact, then that must imply that $H_0(X)$ is equal to 0. 
And secondly what about $H_1(X)$, shouldn't it be 0 also.

It will be great if someone can kindly clear the doubts I am having .

Comment: The boundary map $d_0$ is $X_0 \rightarrow 0$, so $H_0(X) = \text{ker } d_0 / \text{im } d_1 = X_0/\text{im }d_1 = X_0/ \text{ker } \epsilon$ and this is equal to $\text{im } \epsilon$ by the first isomorphism theorem for modules, and $\epsilon$ is surjective by exactness so $\text{im } \epsilon = M$. Then $H_0(X) = M$ follows.

Comment: To clear the confusion you are having, $X$ is not exact, only $X \xrightarrow \epsilon M$

Answer (score 1):

By exactness, $P_1\to P_0 \to M\to 0$ gives you that $P_0/\text{im}(P_1\to P_0)\cong M$. The complex you are using to compute homology is slightly different, as you don't have $M$ there. Instead, the end is $P_1\to P_0\to 0$, so $P_0$ is the $0$th kernel, and hence $H_0(P_*)=P_0/\text{im}(P_1\to P_0)$.

Comment: Okay so you are saying from the initial sequence I.e the complex of $.... \rightarrow X_n \xrightarrow {d_{n}} X_{n-1}......X_1\xrightarrow {d_{1}} X_0 \rightarrow 0$, we should consider $ker(d_0)=X_0$, while computing $H_0(X)$

Comment: Yep. You drop the ultimate thing, in this case $M$.